# Are there side effects to Postgres 12's NOT MATERIALIZED directive?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, execution-plan, postgresql-12

I was doing some performance benchmarking on some of my company's SQL, comparing PG10 to PG12. We use **a lot** of CTEs in our code, and PG12 didn't natively optimize the CTEs, so the performance was the same between PG10 and PG12.

My next experiment was to add the `NOT MATERIALIZED` directive to the CTEs and the result was astounding:  it cut query times dramatically (halved them in some cases).

I read [here](https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-12-with-materialize/) that `MATERIALIZED` was the default functionality prior to PG12. And that functionality would write all the contents of the CTE into a temporary location.

So my question is mainly around `NOT MATERIALIZED`:

1. What does the `NOT MATERIALIZED` functionality do with the data behind the scenes in contrast to `MATERIALIZED`?
2. Are there any side effects to `NOT MATERIALIZED` I should be aware of before refactoring our codebase?

Comment: Interesting, I though `not materialized` is the default now in Postgres 12

Comment: I think it is - maybe I worded something incorrectly?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) - `However, if a WITH query is non-recursive and side-effect-free (that is, it is a SELECT containing no volatile functions) then it can be folded into the parent query, allowing joint optimization of the two query levels. By default, this happens if the parent query references the WITH query just once, but not if it references the WITH query more than once.` - see the end of my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's explained very well in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

> A useful property of WITH queries is that they are normally evaluated
> only once per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred
> to more than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries. Thus,
> expensive calculations that are needed in multiple places can be
> placed within a WITH query to avoid redundant work. Another possible
> application is to prevent unwanted multiple evaluations of functions
> with side-effects.

So far, so good, **BUT**:

> However, the other side of this coin is that the optimizer is not able
> to push restrictions from the parent query down into a
> multiply-referenced WITH query, since that might affect all uses of
> the WITH query's output when it should affect only one. The
> multiply-referenced WITH query will be evaluated as written, without
> suppression of rows that the parent query might discard afterwards.

So, as pointed out in the example given, if you have a query like this:

```
WITH w AS (
    SELECT * FROM big_table  -- big_table has an INDEX on a field called key!
)
SELECT * FROM w AS w1 
  JOIN w AS w2 ON w1.key = w2.ref  -- w is called TWICE, so DEFAULT is MATERIALIZED
                                   -- PostgreSQL can't take advantage of big_table.key
WHERE w2.key = 123;
```

So, in this case:

> the WITH query will be materialized, producing a temporary copy of big_table that is > then joined with itself — without benefit of any index

Far better to have:

```
WITH w AS NOT MATERIALIZED (
    SELECT * FROM big_table
)
SELECT * FROM w AS w1 JOIN w AS w2 ON w1.key = w2.ref
WHERE w2.key = 123;
```

So that the optimizer can "fold" the CTE query "into" the main query and make use of the `INDEX` on the `key` field of `big_table`!

Re. the `DEFAULT` of `NOT MATERIALIZED`:

> However, if a WITH query is non-recursive and side-effect-free (that
> is, it is a SELECT containing no volatile functions) then it can be
> folded into the parent query, allowing joint optimization of the two
> query levels. By default, this happens if the parent query references
> the WITH query just once, but not if it references the WITH query more
> than once.

So the `DEFAULT` is `NOT MATERIALIZED` if:

```
    the_query IS NOT recursive 
AND the_query is_side_effect_free 
AND the_query is_referenced_only_once
```

otherwise you have to tell PostgreSQL to use `NOT MATERIALIZED`.

The only small problem that I see is that testing will be required to see if
`NOT MATERIALIZED` is an improvement or not? I can see circumstances where the balance will swing between the two depending on table size, fields selected and indexes on the fields and tables used in the CTE - in other words, there's no substitute for knowledge and experience. The DBA isn't dead and gone yet! :-)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed reply. I am particularly interested in your last paragraph where you say that you can "see circumstances where the balance will swing between the two" i.e. between MATERIALIZED and NOT MATERIALIZED options. I was wondering if you could provide more detail on this comment?

Comment: I don't have any **concrete** examples to hand, but the fact that one or the other isn't what the system does all the time **without** any choice available to the dev/dba implies that (the very clever) PostgreSQL system developers have looked at this and decided that the dev/dba should have a choice in the matter. This (to me) implies that the balance between `MATERIALIZED` and `NOT MATERIALIZED` is a fluid one and that, **say** (my impression/opinion) if the number of records changes, or further subqueries are added to a complex query, the optimal plan will be better with one or the other.

Comment: @Zeruno **Ideally**, the optimiser would be able to determine the better course of action, however for the moment, it is not. BTW, this is also true for the mighty Oracle -  see [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) - search for "hint". If you were to ask a question (you could point back here for context) to get an example of such a shift in balance (using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for example, then I would upvote the question and any decent answers! (+1 for your comment!).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply and useful reference. I have actually asked a very similar question over at SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60701158/when-does-the-postgresql-12-cte-materialized-option-provide-an-optimization-adva/60702318#60702318 and came across your comment while still looking into the topic.

Comment: IMHO, your question belongs here and not on StackOverflow (but +1 anyway)! If I were you, I'd ask it again here and point back to that question. Edit your question on SO to point here explaining that DBA.SE is the better forum and that to avoid duplication of answers/effort, could those who wish to answer please  respond here. The example given by [`@steve`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60702318/470530) does not tackle the question as asked - I believe that you would receive more relevant answers here!

Comment: I'll give it a shot over here then... thank you so much for your advice and interest. :)

Comment: Please post the link in this thread for my attention - I am interested!

Comment: Here it is - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/262178/when-does-the-postgresql-12-cte-materialized-option-provide-an-optimization-adva

Answer (score 0):

The only side effect should be performance-related (which I guess makes it the main effect, not a side effect).  If there is any other side effects, those would have to be bugs.  It is bit weird that that there is no "let the planner decide" setting.